# python, how to call function in as parameter in self.response.out.write()

Tags: python

```
class GuestBook(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write(
            '<h2>You wrote:</h2> %s'   %self.request.get('content')     )
```

I want to pass this: `%self.request.get('content')`  into a function. And use function return in the old place.I am python newbie. I tried.but failed. need help!

This is my function; I defined it in the same class as below.

```
def ept(str)
        str = str + " is good."
        return str
```

And I call it in the old place like:

```
ept(%self.request.get('content'))
```

Could anybody help me, what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you ought to (re-)read about [string interpolation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

The `%` is an operator applicable to string and unicode objects, so such an object must precede its usage. So you could do

```
def ept(s):
    return "%s is good" % s

ept(self.request.get('content'))
```

`%` is applicable to integers as well, but that's a different story.